# Is there a way to hide my BD password and username in spring (gradle)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I'm programming an application in java using spring. And I have encrypted (jasypt) the credentials of the database that I have in the .yaml file, but to decrypt it forces me to have the password in the same .yaml file. Is there a way to have this password separately? for now I have only found answers for projects made with maven and my project uses gradle.

This is how my application.yaml looks like

```
spring:
application:
name: ticketing-service
  datasource:
    url: DB 
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    username: ENC(username)
    password: ENC(password)
server:
  port: 8770
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    algorithm: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
    password: password
```

Comment: Don't add DB credentials to `yml`. Add them as environment variables

Comment: Done, as you can see, the only way I found to decrypt my bd credentials is by using jasypt in the same file. Which in my opinion makes no sense.

Comment: @5377037 do you have any advice?